# How does the Torsion of two vector fields act on their corresponding flows?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, connections, lie-derivative

Let $X$ and $Y$ be vector fields defined on an open neighborhhod of a smooth manifold $M$ endowed with an (arbitrary) affine connection $\nabla$ (i'm not assuming anything apart from it being a connection on $TM$).

I'm trying to understand the torsion $T(X,Y)=\nabla_X Y - \nabla_Y X - [X,Y]$ of the connection in terms of flows. Here's what i have so far:

Denoting the local flows of $X$ and $Y$ by $\varphi^X_t$ and $\varphi^Y_t$ resp. and their commutator by $\alpha(t)= \varphi^Y_{-t} \varphi^X_{-t}\varphi^Y_t\varphi^X_t$. We have the following relation between the lie bracket and the $\alpha$:

$$[X,Y] = \frac{1}{2} \alpha ''(0)$$

So what i'm left with is finding a way to express $\nabla_X Y - \nabla_Y X$ in terms of flows. Obviously there must be some input from the connection. I tried to compute the flow by exponentiating from the lie algebra of vector fields but i didn't get very far...

This problem made me realize i have no idea how integral curves and parallel are related. A word about how the they relate to each other would in any case be very helpful.

**Ideally I'd like to have an expression for $\nabla_X Y - \nabla_Y X$ in terms of parallel transport and the flows of $X$ and $Y$.** Is there such a charactrization?

Comment: Perhaps, It would help If you wrote the covariant derivatives in terms of the lie derivative. This page does the opposite (lie derivative in terms of covariant) but in a 'physicist' notation http://www.physicspages.com/2013/02/17/lie-derivative-in-terms-of-the-covariant-derivative/

Comment: I don't think it's possible to write the covariant derivative in terms of lie derivatives. After all I could just as well add an $End(TM)$-valued 1-form to the connection and the lie derivatives wouldn't notice.

Comment: Take a look at this paper. Apparently it's done in the fifth reference http://www.calpoly.edu/~kmorriso/Research/LieBracket.pdf

Comment: In  Kobayashi & Nomizu, Foundations of Differential Geometry the torsion tensor comes to torsion form $\Theta$, since the riemann connection is obtained from connection on the Frames bundle L(M), the connection $\nabla_X Y$ is expressed in terms of horizontal lift of integral curves, maybe be usefull.

Comment: @Saal Hardali: Could you post what you find. The answer seems like it should be pretty interesting.

Answer (score 3):

Back in Élie Cartan's papers (but I don't remember specifically which) there is a discussion of the torsion as the *translational* part of the holonomy of an affine connection, whereas curvature is the *rotational* part (in the Riemannian case). You should also read [this discussion](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20493/what-is-torsion-in-differential-geometry-intuitively) on mathoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

So from Samelson *Lie Bracket and Curvature*, its shown that

$$ (\nabla_Xs)^v =[X^h,s^v]$$ where $ X \in \Gamma(TM)$ and $s \in \Gamma(E)$ and $\nabla$ is the covariant derivative on $E$. The $s^v$ is the vertical extension and is defined as below [image]

Like wise the $X^h$ is the horizontal lift of the vector field and is defined as [image]

So
 $$ \nabla_XY-\nabla_YX = \pi([X^h,Y^v] - [Y^h,X^v]) $$

Where $\pi$ is the vertical projection.Therefore

$$\nabla_XY - \nabla_YX = \pi(\frac12(\beta^{''}(0)-\gamma^{''}(0)))$$

Where $$ \beta = \varphi_{-t}^{Y^v}\varphi_{-t}^{X^h}\varphi_{t}^{Y^v}\varphi_{t}^{X^h}$$ and $$ \gamma = \varphi_{-t}^{X^v}\varphi_{-t}^{Y^h}\varphi_{t}^{X^v}\varphi_{t}^{Y^h}$$

where $\varphi_{t}^{Y^v} $,$ \varphi_{t}^{X^h} $,$ \varphi_{t}^{X^v}$ and $ \varphi_{t}^{Y^h} $ are the flows of $ Y^v $, $X^h$, $X^v$ and $Y^h$ respectively.

I don't know if this makes any sense but I think by finding a way to horizontally lift and vertically extend the flows you would have a characterization  of the covariant derivative in terms of the flows of $X$ and $Y$.